# Show that $\mathbb{F}_7[\sqrt{-1}] := \{a+b\sqrt{-1}$ | $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_7\}$ is a ring

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory

I'm trying to solve this group theory problem, and I'm really not sure how to approach this. The question is:

Show that $\mathbb{F}_7[\sqrt{-1}] := \{a+b\sqrt{-1}$ | $a,b \in \mathbb{F}_7\}$ is a ring.

I have been stuck on this problem for hours and I really cannot figure it out.

This is my progress so far:

$(a+b\sqrt{-1}) + (c+d\sqrt{-1}) = (a+c) + (b+d)\sqrt{-1}$

I'm not sure what I'm doing, I'll appreciate it if anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Don't forget that you should show some effort.

Comment: You need to show that the set in question, with the obvious addition and multiplication, satisfies the the ring axioms. So, write down the ring axioms, and for each one, ask yourself: does this hold for all the elements of my set?

Comment: I edited the main post and added my progress so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably help to know that $\mathbb{F}_{7}$ denotes the field of $7$ elements. Moreover, since $7$ is a prime number $\mathbb{F}_{7} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{7}$, the integers modulo $7$. To show that a set is a ring, we have to show that it is 1.) closed under addition, 2.) multiplication, 3.) left/right distributive, and 4.) each element has an additive inverse. Let $R = \mathbb{F}_{7}[i]$, where $i = \sqrt{-1}$. 
1.) Let $a + bi , c + di \in R$. Then $(a+bi) + (c+di) = (a+c) + (b+d)i \in R$, since $\mathbb{F}_{7}$ is a field and hence closed under addition. 
2.) Let $a+bi , c+di \in R$. $(a+bi)(c+di) = (ac + bdi^{2}) + (ad+bc)i = (ac-bd) + (ad+bc)i \in R$, once again by the fact that $\mathbb{F}_{7}$ is a field, and is closed under addition and multiplication. 
3.) I will show left distributivity, right distributivity is similar. Let $a+bi, c+di, e+fi \in R$. Then $(a+bi)(c+di + e+fi) = (a+bi)((c+e)+(d+f)i) = (a(c+e) - b(d+f)) + (b(c+e) + a(d+f))i) = (ac+ae-bd-bf) + (bc+be+ad+af)i = (a+bi)(c+di) + (a+bi)(e+fi)$. 
4.) Let $a+bi \in R$ then its additive inverse is $-a-bi \in R$, because $\mathbb{F}_{7}$ is a field and so the additive inverse exists and it is unique.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Your ring is $\mathbb Z[X]/(7,X^2+1)$.